# How to create new spreadsheet in drive with some text and tab on form submit

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a new folder on form submit and dump the link to the folder where the form response goes to in a particular column. I'm not familiar with app script. This is what the initial code looks like. This code dumps all the form response in the "Clients" tab but leaves only the link to the drive folder empty.

```
//-----------------------------------------------
// *********** CONSTANTS ***********
var ARCHIVE_FOLDER = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("settings").getRange(8, 9).getValue();
var ARCHIVE_FOLDER_DOCS = ARCHIVE_FOLDER;

var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//---------------------------

function installTrigger(){
  var sheetID = SS.getId();

  var folder = getParentFolder(sheetID);
  SS.getSheetByName("settings").getRange(2, 9).setValue(sheetID);
  SS.getSheetByName("settings").getRange(8, 9).setValue(folder);  

}

function getParentFolder(sheetID){

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetID);
  var folders = file.getParents();
  while (folders.hasNext()){
    var folder = folders.next().getId();
  }

  return folder;
}
```

And here is another script this is where the form submit is dumping the data i actually want the new folder URL to be dump in Col6

```
function logResponseClientSheet(e) {
    if (e) {

       Logger.log(e);

       var response = {  
          timestamp: Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-6', 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm'),
          owner: e.name,
          client_domain: e.domain,
          client_homepage: e.homepage,
          client_goal: e.kpi,
          client_start_date: e.start_date,
          client_end_date: e.end_date,
          client_poc_name: e.poc_name,
          client_description: e.description,
          client_poc_email: e.poc_email
        }
        var sheets = SS.getSheetByName("Clients");

      Logger.log(response);

        sheets.getRange(sheets.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 11)
            .setValues([
                ["Active", response.owner, response.client_domain, response.client_homepage, response.client_goal, '', 
                 response.client_start_date, response.client_end_date, response.client_description, response.client_poc_name, response.client_poc_email ]
            ]);
            Logger.log("exit logResponseClientSheet");    }
}
```